# Multiple agents on one host

Tags: puppet, puppet-agent

Is it possible two run multiple puppet agents with different user rights on one host?

I have a server which should be administered by two non related users through puppet. (one user account for the developer and one root account for the server team)

Comment: It is possible, but it would be pretty unusual.

Comment: And how would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The non-root account can just run `puppet agent --one-time --no-daemonize` and any other flavor of `puppet agent`.

Configuration and persistent data will be looked up and stored in

- `~/.puppet/` for Puppet 3.x and older
- `~/.puppetlabs/` for Puppet 4.x and later

Things you want to make sure via `~/.puppet/puppet.conf`:

- you use a distinct `certname` setting for the secondary agent
- you likely want to use an alternate `server` as well so that the certificate is not trusted by your main master (yes, you will need a new Puppet master if you want this)
- `vardir` and its children such as `ssldir` and `statedir` are distinct from the system central location and writeable to the user (it's safest **not** to touch these at all - the defaults are quite sane; see also `puppet agent --configprint all`).

Also, the manifest should be limited to resources that an unpriviliged agent can manage, such as

- files owned by the user
- cron jobs of the user's
- Ruby gems installed in the user's home directory

etc.

Comment: Why shouldn't the certname not be trusted by my main master? Can't I just have both certs (root, non-root user) on my master and deploy to the agent by using the same method as in the agent's case? (Running the master binary with different user privileges)

Comment: If you feel comfortable trusting this certificate, then yes, just use the regular master. There are no implicit security implications. You should probably not run a second master process, though. From the master's POV, the two agents on that one box are distinct nodes, that is all. (If you *were* to run two masters, you would have to use an alternate `masterport` for one of them. But if they share the CA after all, that setup will become quite messy I imagine.)

Comment: So It would be better to run two separate master instances with different masterports and different trusted certnames. If I want to have two managed master nodes (one non-root and one root instance)

Comment: I think I caused confustion now. **If** you want distinct masters, one distinct machines, don't touch `masterport`. Two **masters** on the master host would need distinct ports. *Don't do either of those.* Just create the unprivileged agent. Make sure it has a `certname` different from the main agent. Create a `node` block for that certificate name on the master, so that it can compile a manifest for the secondary agent.